# cant do native client demos

Tags: browser, google-chrome, google-nativeclient

I have followed online tutorial, http://code.google.com/chrome/nativeclient/docs/tutorial.html
and have Chrome 10 installed on Ubuntu 10.04. However, I am getting this error, when
trying examples.

For demo helloworld c, it get stuck in LOADING.

For demo GetURL, it throws 'exception: TypeError: Cannot call method
'getUrl' of null'

For demo PIGenerator, it's missing plug-in.

Any ideas what this is about. Thanks

Comment: What OS are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have Chrome 10 on Linux, it is known not to work. This has been fixed in version 11. More information regarding that in this bug tracker.

http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/issues/detail?id=1416

and

https://groups.google.com/group/native-client-discuss